# Chaining observables that receive response from primeng confirm service

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

Im using the confirm.service of PrimeNG in my app. I need to present an array of an indeterminate number of messages to the user just to show the message with an Accept button.

With my current code, only the last message is printed.

```
mensajes.forEach(mensaje => {
  this.utility.openConfirmDialog(this._confirmationService, {
    message: mensaje.mensaje + ' ' + mensaje.restoMensaje,
    header: 'Atención',
    showReject: false
  }).subscribe(ca => ca);
});
```

I would like that the confirmDialog wait until user click on the button.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Due to nature of confirmDialog service of PrimeNG, I come to a solution not related with Observables or any Rx.js derivates.

I simply created another component which will be responsable of presenting confirmDialogs. Using @Input and @Output, the flow of the app go from main component to child component and back again, giving the responsibility of presenting another confirmDialog to the main component.

If someone face this kind of problem, drop a line here and I will post my solution.